# Rails 4 upgrade to 5, difference in polymorphic "has_one" + "includes"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, upgrade, has-one

Upgrading my app from 4.1 -> 5.1 and I hit a weird bug using a conditional "has_one" with "includes" on a polymorphic relationship.

The "has_one" implementation

```
has_one :latest_event,
        -> { order(created_at: :desc).limit(1) },
        class_name: :WarehouseEvent,
        as: :scheduleable  // (polymorphic name)
```

Buggy Results

```
Order.includes(:latest_event).map(&:latest_event).select(&:present?).count
=> 1

Order.map(&:latest_event).select(&:present?).count
=> 562
```

(before upgrading, both results would show 562)

The logged output shows the `order(:created_at)` and `limit 1` was applied to the giant `SELECT ..... WHERE ID IN ( ...ids... )` generated by the "includes" (rather than each subquery).

Obviously, I don't *need* to use "includes," but it is already baked deep into my app.  Any ideas??

EDIT:  There are much better ways to find the count, this is the simplest way I could think of to demonstrate the root problem.

Comment: Depending on what db you have you could replace that mess with something like `WarehouseEvent.order(created_at: :desc).group(:parent_id).distinct("ON(parent_id)")`. It makes very little sense to query one model and then use `.map` to flip it, why not just start with the model you actually want?

Comment: If I understand this query correctly `Order.includes(&:latest_event).map(&:latest_event).select(&:present?).count`, you want to know the count of `Order` records having a `latest_event`, right? You can simplify this by doing `Order.joins(:latest_event).count` or `WarehouseEvent.where(parent_type: 'Order').group(:parent_id).count`

Comment: Also, a `has_one` relation in Rails already applies this `limit(1)` for you, you can remove it safely from your scope.

Comment: I edited the question to address your comments regarding the count.

Removing the "limit(1)" fixed the immediate bug, so thanks MrYoshiji for that.  Because it produced different results with Rails 4, I submitted an issue to Rails.  https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32200